# How to change cells colors in specified columns?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

I picked up this code to select and change the interior color (green) of the EntireRow when the AtiveCell is behind the 6 Row.

I need to select and change the interior color (Color = 9359529) of the column "I" and "J" of the Row where is the ActiveCell. Is similar to this code but do not need the entire row, just the columns I and J.

```vb
Dim lTarget As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    If Target.Row >= 6 Then
       
        If Not lTarget Is Nothing Then
            lTarget.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
        
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 9359529
        Set lTarget = Target

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just your example and what I think you're asking this is the simplest way to do what I think you're asking.

You either have just one row in the selection - or you just want the first row changed

This can be changed to use a Range object - but this is easy to understand

```
Dim lTarget As Range
Const TargetCol1    As Integer = 9
Const TargetCol2    As Integer = 10

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    If Target.Row >= 6 Then
        If Not lTarget Is Nothing Then
            lTarget.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
        
        Cells(Target.Row, TargetCol1).Interior.Color = 9359529
        Cells(Target.Row, TargetCol2).Interior.Color = 9359529
        
        Set lTarget = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thank dbmicth, It's exactly what i need to finish my work.

Comment: Great - if it worked for you can you finish up and check it off as the answer? Many thanks.

Comment: Of couse yes dbmitch. I'm tryig to understand where can i do that because i'm new in stackoverflow. I hope i did it in the right place. Many thanks for your precious answer.

Comment: Mr dbmitch, the code it's giving an error on line "Cells(Target.Row, TargetCol1).Interior.Color = 9359529". Maybe is because i have a conditional formatting with a formula that said if =$I16="" then keep all the row of the table in grey color. Otherwise, the row stay with color=0 and all the other conditional formatting colors that i specified for some columns. Maybe is the raison to this code it'ss giving an error on "Cells(Target.Row, TargetCol1).Interior.Color = 9359529". When i work without protect worsheet, it works good but when put the password to protect the page, it's start the error

Comment: The code works perfectly as long as the page is not protected. After protecting her, it start gives an error.

Comment: You didn't say anything about protected cells. You should open a new question

Comment: You didn't say anything about protected cells. You should open a new question

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet SelectionChange

- Many thanks to Tragamor for pointing out the many flaws of my previous attempts.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private lTarget As Range
Private FirstPassed As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 6
    Const Cols As String = "I:J"
    Const iColor As Long = 9359529
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    Set rrg = Rows(FirstRow).Resize(Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(rrg, Target)
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then Set irg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, Columns(Cols))
    
    If FirstPassed Then
        If irg Is Nothing Then
            If Not lTarget Is Nothing Then
                lTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Set lTarget = Nothing
            End If
        Else
            If Not lTarget Is Nothing Then
                lTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
            irg.Interior.Color = iColor
            Set lTarget = irg
        End If
    Else
        rrg.Columns(Cols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        If Not irg Is Nothing Then
            irg.Interior.Color = iColor
            Set lTarget = irg
        End If
        FirstPassed = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This will leave behind highlight from the previous activecell which triggered the change. You may want to update with a global/worksheet variable to hold that value and clear upon change.

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008. As the code of dbmitch, both do exactly what i need. Many thanks to both for your precious help to finish my work..

Comment: VBasic2008, the code it's giving an error on line "rrg.Columns(Cols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone". Maybe is because i have a conditional formatting with a formula that said if =$I16="" then keep all the row of the table in grey color. Otherwise, the row stay with color=0 and all the other conditional formatting colors that i specified for some columns. Maybe is the raison to this code it's giving an error on "rrg.Columns(Cols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone". When i work with the code without protect worsheet, it works good but when i put the password to protect the page, it's start the error.

Comment: When i protect the page, first, give error on (lTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone) -Code:  "Else
            If Not lTarget Is Nothing Then
                lTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If" and after that, when i end the error, goes to another error on ( rrg.Columns(Cols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone) - Code: "Else
        rrg.Columns(Cols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        If Not irg Is Nothing Then"

Comment: The code works perfectly as long as the page is not protected. After protecting her, it start gives an error.